# Wrong formatting on save on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, settings, prettier

VSCode started to format my code in the wrong way.

E.g. I set it to use single quotes but VSCode changes it to double quotes on save.

I’ve disabled all extensions which could format code except for Prettier, checked all Prettier settings for User and Workflow (they are the same for now), and set Prettier as a default formatter for all types of files which I am working with.

But still, a code is formatted in the wrong way.

What else do I need to check to find what exactly format my files on save? How to fix this problem?

settings.json:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true
}
```